# Perl expect - how to control timeout on target machine

Tags: perl, send, expect

I am a newbie to perl. I am using perl expect module to spawn to a remote system. Execute a set of commands there one after another using the send module(like $exp->send("my command as string goes here\n"). The problem is the commands that I execute take some time for processing . And before all the command finish the remote machine gets timed out and I come back to my host machine prompt. Can you please help me how to handle this.?

I have one more question. I have a command which returns 2 values after execution(say I am doing a print for 2 values on remote machine). I want to capture these 2 values and pass as argument to the next command using send module. How do I do this.

Pls help me with this problem.

Thanks.

I just found out something about the expect module. There is an undef option that can be used with expect like $exp->expect(undef). This will wait indefinitely and lets all commands finish their processing. But the problem is that, it does not return back the control to the host machine. There is one more option of using expect with eof which will wait until it encounters an eof and then returns to the host machine. Although no idea precisely how to use it. An elegant solution that I found is to use ssh to run commands on remote machine rather than using expect in which case we do not have to deal with timeouts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out something about the expect module. There is an undef option that can be used with expect like $exp->expect(undef). This will wait indefinitely and lets all commands finish their processing. But the problem is that, it does not return back the control to the host machine. There is one more option of using expect with eof which will wait until it encounters an eof and then returns to the host machine. Although no idea precisely how to use it. An elegant solution that I found is to use ssh to run commands on remote machine rather than using expect in which case we do not have to deal with timeouts. :)

Comment: anybody with any solution for expect??